# vue-multiselect display number selected

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vue-multiselect

Is there a way to display for example "3 selected" instead of each selection with vue-multiselect.  I have a design where there is limited room to display each selection.

The tag slot seems to only allow changing each selection.

Answer (score 1):

Should have looked at the source before posting the question.  There is a "selection" slot that isn't in the documentation.

It gives you an array of "values" which you can then grab the length of to display.